# Serialized hash cannot be saved on postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In my app I've got a table named `contacts` with the `areas_of_interest` field. This field should store hashes sent by user via form. However my database reject those hashes and leave this field blank every time when I want to save it:

Schema:

```
create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.text "areas_of_interest"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_contacts_on_user_id"
end
```

Contact Model:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user        
  serialize :areas_of_interest
  ...
end
```

ContactsController:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.update(contact_params)
      format.html do
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Contact has been updated'
      end
    else
      format.html do
        render :edit, notice: 'Error'
      end
    end
  end
end

private

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(
    ...
    :areas_of_interest,
    ...
  )
end
```

And the hash sent from client looks like this:

`{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"0", "third"=>"0", "fourth"=>"0", "fifth"=>"1"}`

What possibly do I do here wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: change `:areas_of_interest` to `areas_of_interest: {}`

Comment: Where? In Model?

Comment: in `params.require(:contact).permit(...`

Comment: If you have postgres - use jsonb or hstore data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format appears to be a dump of a Ruby `Hash`. [`serialize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) is done using [YAML](https://yaml.org/). It would look like this.

```
{ first: "1", second: "0", third: "0", fourth: "0", fifth: "1"}
```

But there's a better way. Since you're using Postgres you can take advantage of [Postgres JSONB](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb) and send the data as JSON. The serialization will be handled for you, you have all the power of [Postgres's JSON search facilities](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html), and JSON is a standard format that most languages can produce.

```
{ "first": "1", "second": "0", "third": "0", "fourth": "0", "fifth": "1"}

create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.jsonb :areas_of_interest
  t.index [:areas_of_interest], using: :gin
end
```

Nothing special is needed in `Contact`. Use `contact.areas_of_interest` like any other field, but it can take Hashes and Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`areas_of_interest` looks like it's getting filtered out by `strong_params`. I think what you need is something like this to indicate which keys should be allowed:

```
params.require(:contact).permit(
  ...
  areas_of_interest: [:first, :second, :third, :fourth, :fifth],
  ...
)
```

I also highly recommend using the `jsonb` type as mentioned by @Schwern.